Find Session Advanced isn’t working in Unreal Engine 5
I was trying to create a mechanism to invite friends to the lobby. So to make it work I had to reparent my custom gameinstance blueprint to Advanced Friends GameInstance. After that Find Session Advanced just stopped finding any servers in the built version. It works fine in editor.
Create Advanced SessionGame Instance Class SettingsFind Session Advanced
After returning the parent class of gameinstance back to Game Instance the session search worked, but now accepting a request to join the lobby does nothing.
